# Localized routes with attribute routing in MVC5

Tags: localization, routes

Is it possible to have localized routes with attibute routing feature in MVC5?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.
Just add the part of the localized url to the attribute routing

Comment: I mean that whole URL would be localized Home/Index would be the same  as Domu/Index; Koti/Index atc...

Comment: That is more of a challenge. You could add all translation into the attribute routing. After all you can specify multiple routes. Otherwise you would have to build something dynamic.